# New index based on existing index

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that is similar to this one but with more rows (in the thousands), I am trying to create a new index from a previous index as follows. The old index and category is data i have and the new index is the column I am trying to generate:

| old index | Category | new index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FIFO1_1 | 1 |
| 2 | FIFO1_1 | 2 |
| 3 | FIFO1_1 | 3 |
| 4 | FIFO1_1 | 13 |
| 5 | FIFO1_1 | 14 |
| 6 | FIFO1_1 | 15 |
| 1 | FIFO1_2 | 4 |
| 2 | FIFO1_2 | 5 |
| 3 | FIFO1_2 | 6 |
| 4 | FIFO1_2 | 16 |
| 5 | FIFO1_2 | 17 |
| 6 | FIFO1_2 | 18 |
| 1 | FIFO1_3 | 7 |
| 2 | FIFO1_3 | 8 |
| 3 | FIFO1_3 | 9 |
| 4 | FIFO1_3 | 19 |
| 5 | FIFO1_3 | 20 |
| 6 | FIFO1_3 | 21 |
| 1 | FIFO1_4 | 10 |
| 2 | FIFO1_4 | 11 |
| 3 | FIFO1_4 | 12 |
| 4 | FIFO1_4 | 22 |
| 5 | FIFO1_4 | 23 |
| 6 | FIFO1_4 | 24 |

So, the logic here is that I want to have a window of a specific number (in this example it's 3) and then starting from the first category FIFO1_1 I want to start the index at 1 until 3. Then I will jump to the second category which is FIFO1_2 with 4,5,6 and then to FIFO1_3 and so on. When I reach the last category FIFO1_4 , I want to start again at the first category FIFO1_1 with the last value I reached which was 13 and repeat the same process. In the real data I have 7 categories and each have 11520 rows. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: This seems like strange logic and the question is a possible example of the XY problem... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Hey David, I don't think this is an XY problem. It's a strange situation due to the way the data is being collected. So what I am trying to do here is to correct the index based on a time-series process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this instead.  I assumes you have the SAME number of rows per category.  It also assumes that you have already sorted by category and old index.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    priorStep = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"old index", Int64.Type}, {"Category", type text}, {"new index", Int64.Type}}),
    generate_new_index =
        let 
            window = 2, //define window here
            categories = List.Count(List.Distinct(priorStep[Category])), // make sure priorStep[Category] matches prior step and category column name
            rows = Table.RowCount(priorStep) // make sure priorStep is here
        in
            List.Generate( () =>
                [ n = 0, index = 1],
                each  [n] < rows,
                each 
                [
                    n = [n] + 1,
                    index = 
                        Number.Mod(n,window) + 1 
                        + (Number.RoundUp((n+1)/(rows/categories),0)-1)*window
                        + Number.RoundDown(Number.Mod(n,rows/categories)/window,0)*(window*categories)
                ],
                each [index]
            ),
    add_new_index = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(priorStep) & {generate_new_index}, Table.ColumnNames(priorStep)&{"new_index"}) // name new the column here
in
    add_new_index
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, this is working until each reach the first window ( so my window was 16 and it jumped from 16 to 113 which is perfect but then it just continued normally with 1 increment) but the good thing is that it's not messing with any pivoting/unpivoting. My data has 7 different categories (instead of 4) and for every category there are 11520 rows (instead of 6) and i want the window to be 16 (instead of 3). How can I tweak you code to make it work please?

Comment: instead of window = 2 it should be window = 16.  Is it supposed to do something different?  Can you explain?  Is it maybe 16 to 113 to 113+15 and then another jump and consecutive 16???

Comment: Sure, so if the window for example is 2 as in your sample code. The output should be  [1, 2, 9, 10, 17, 18, 3, 4, 11, 12, 19, 20, 5, 6, 13, 14, 21, 22, 7, 8, 15, 16, 23, 24]

Comment: see updated code to handle this pattern,  you must ensure that rows / (window*categories) is an integer!

Comment: It's working perfectly, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but I have no idea why you would want data in this format

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Number=3,
#"Added Index2" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Sort", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
Repeats=List.Count(List.Distinct(Source[Category])),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index2", {"Category"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Sort","old index","Index"}, {"Sort","old index","Index"}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded data", each [Index] <= Number),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "new index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Filtered Rows2" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded data", each [Index] > Number),
#"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "new index", Number*Repeats+1, 1, Int64.Type),
combined = #"Added Index" & #"Added Index1",
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(combined,{{"Sort", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Sort", "Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, where did you define the window? Cause in my original data the window will be 16 with 7 categories

Comment: Sure, I will. I am testing it right now. Do you mind explaining the logic briefly? I am new to power bi.

Comment: Add a sort index. Group by category. Within each group add an index. Expand everything. Filter to get all items with index <window. Add new index.  Filter to get all items with index > window.  Add new index starting at window*category count+1. Put those two together. Resort. Remove extra helper columns.  You can step through each part to see what it is doing by clicking on each step on the right

Comment: Hey, the category is unpivoted and the code you provided it causing it to pivot again and the results are messy. Any way around it?

Comment: I mean the categories used to be a columns for every category ( column for FIFO1_1 and column for FIFO1_2 and so on) but to get it in the shape in the question i unpivoted it.

Comment: I don't know what your comment means, unfortunately.  I started with your sample data and got the desired output.  If your real data does not look like the sample data, there may be issue. Remember that if you are adding my code to the end of your existing code, then you need to replace Source with with "#NameOfYourLastPriorStepGoesHere"